# Redactor: Make dropdown menu look like an actual dropdown

Tags: redactor

Imperavi's WYSIWYG jQuery editor - [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/) - is a wonderful piece of code with clear documentation. However in some cases it lacks configurability.

I am trying to add a dropdown menu. Their documentation demonstrates [how to do precisely this](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/dropdown/), but the end result is just a square button with an image. I would like to make the dropdown "button" look like an actual dropdown menu (like a selector). Would this be possible without any deep hacks?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out some of their plugins? (like FontSize, FontFamily etc)

http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins/

--iM

Answer (score 0):

Create a button css or make Font Awesome's icon:

```
<style type="text/css">
.redactor_toolbar li a.re-advanced {
    background-image: url(/img/advanced.png);
}
.redactor_toolbar li a.re-advanced:hover {
    background-image: url(/img/advanced-hover.png);
}
</style>
```

Create the plugin:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.advanced = {
    init: function ()
    {
        var dropdown = {};

        dropdown['point1'] = { title: 'Point 1', callback: this.point1callback };
        dropdown['point2'] = { title: 'Point 2', callback: this.point2callback };

        this.buttonAdd('advanced', 'Advanced', false, dropdown);
    },
    point1callback: function(buttonName, buttonDOM, buttonObj, e)
    {
        alert(buttonName);
    },
    point2callback: function(buttonName, buttonDOM, buttonObj, e)
    {
        alert(buttonName);
    }
};
```

Call Redactor with the plugin:

```
 $(function()
    {
        $('#redactor').redactor({
            plugins: ['advanced']
        });
    });
```

You could view a working example here:
http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/dropdown/